# Difference between "savedInstanceState" and "bundle" in Android with Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm starting to use Xamarin and I already saw tutorials and looked over the internet for a specific answer to this question, but with no lucky.

Here's the question.

When I create a new project with VisualStudio choosing a Xamarin C# Android application, it automatically creates a MainActivity.cs with this code:
[image: code_1]

Note this code: 
`protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)` 
and 
`base.OnCreate(bundle);`

Then I added a new activity (right click on the project, Add, New item, Activity, Add) called Activity1.cs, but here in the new activity the code automatically generated by Xamarin is different:
[image: code_2]

Note:
`protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` 
and 
`base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);`

**Why is "bundle" replaced by "savedInstanceState"? What does change if I put "bundle" in Activity1 or vice-versa?**

Thanks a lot to anyone can help me, and sorry if it seems a silly question.

Comment: please DO NOT post code as images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundle` and `savedInstanceState` are just names of the parameter so there is no difference between them. In C# parameter names does not matter.

Here is a description of the parameter from [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnCreate/p/Android.OS.Bundle/) that is passed to `OnCreate` method:

> If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut
>   down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in
>   Activity.OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null.

Comment: Thanks, but where does this parameter (the one contained in "bundle" or "savedInstanceState") come from? Where is it generated?

Comment: @matteventu: It is passed to the activity by the framework itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot again ^_^